# independent elemants onclick, same class name vanila js

Tags: javascript

i want to have multiple elements with same class that act independently, after 1 night of seeking if "forEach" has any 'forEach:active' i end up with code below, but i feel kind of little shame with 'nextSibling of parent of parent' but if is supported by atleast any modern browsers, then is better than nothing.
on codePen is working fine,as well as snippet here.
i wonder if i can find a better version in vanila js for it or if is there anything deprecated that i should change.

```js
//get + button
  const up = document.querySelectorAll('.up');
  //tell to + to increase his previous frend value
  [].forEach.call(up, function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.previousElementSibling.value =
        parseInt(this.previousElementSibling.value) + 1;

    });
  })
        //get -
  const down = document.querySelectorAll('.down');
  //tell to - to decrease his next frend value && and hide 
   //dynamic 
//input if == 0 && show firstAdd button
  [].forEach.call(down, function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.nextElementSibling.value =
        parseInt(this.nextElementSibling.value) - 1;
      if (this.nextElementSibling.value == 0) {
        this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
        this.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'initial';
      }
    });
  })
       //get firstAdd button
  const fAdd = document.querySelectorAll('.firstAdd');
   //tell to it to add dynamic input && to vanish itself after && 
 //set input value = 1
  [].forEach.call(fAdd, function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.previousElementSibling.style.display = 'initial';
      this.previousElementSibling.children[1].children[1].value = 1;
      this.style.display = 'none'
    });
  })
```

```css
  .form-group {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 30px;
    display: none;
  }
  
  .input-group {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  body {
    background: #111;
  }
```

```html
<div class='one'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>value: </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <button class="down">-</button>
      <input type="text" class="myNumber" value='1'>
      <button class="up">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class='firstAdd'>Add</button></div>
<br>
<div class='two'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>value: </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <button class="down">-</button>
      <input type="text" class="myNumber" value='1'>
      <button class="up">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class='firstAdd'>Add</button></div>
```

Comment: If this is working code and you're looking for general feedback then this might be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You don't need to use `[].forEach.call()`. You can just write `up.forEach(...)`

Comment: You never use the `fAdd` variable that you define in the `down` loop.

Comment: ups, it's still there? until i foud the family method as selector a was trying idk what but i was trying